# Set MIP termination gap with PySCIPOpt

Tags: python, scip, mixed-integer-programming

I cannot figure out how to set a MIP gap threshold such that the solver will terminate when the relative difference between the primal and dual solutions is within some value. I am using PySCIPOpt to interact with SCIP.

I am sure there is a simple way (for example if I were using Gurobi's python interface it is just `m.Params.MIPGap = x`, where `m` is the model instance).

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The MIP gap is a parameter in SCIP (and also PySCIPOpt) and can be set like any other:

```
m = pyscipopt.Model()
m.setRealParam('limits/gap', 0.1)
```

For the complete list of available parameters either check the [SCIP documentation](http://scip.zib.de/doc-5.0.1/html/PARAMETERS.php) or run this Python code:

```
m.writeParams('default.set', onlychanged=False)
```

To set a paramter you always need to specify the appropriate type in the function call, i.e., `Bool`, `Int`, `Longint`, `Real`, `Char`, or `String`.